# How to target different type of controls in WPF styles?

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridsplitter

I want to set different backgrounds for `GridSplitter`'s who are horizontal vs vertical. This is because I have a linear gradient and I need to rotate it 90deg depending on the alignment of the grid splitter.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" /> <!-- How to get this red applied to only Vertical for instance? -->
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

So the question is: how do I target vertical splitters and horizontal splitters separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Style.Triggers` to apply setters conditionally.

Answer (score 1):

Okay looks like I got it:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F7F7F7" />
            </Trigger>

            <Trigger Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="red" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```